# Issue when pushing a new branch with Git (sending thousands objects)

Tags: git, push, branch

I have a problem with Git.

I created a branch by doing `git checkout -b mybranch`

I made some commit, and when I'm trying to push it with:

```
git push -u origin mybranch
```

Here is the result:

```
DAVID@DAVID-PC MINGW64 ~/PhpstormProjects/myorigin.server.tld (mybranch)

$ git push --set-upstream origin mybranch
```

Output:

```
Fetching remote heads...   refs/   refs/heads/   refs/tags/ updating
'refs/heads/mybranch   from 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000  
to   62e7a54f88c590b627173b635af8d5760eab1316
    sending 5877 objects
```

What's the point?

I don't know why but I'm unable to create new branches and push it. It seems that Git want always send every object of the repository. I started my branch from an up to date branch.

And after a while I got this error

```
LOCK HTTP error 412 Unable to refresh lock for
http://myorigin.server.tld/info/refs LOCK HTTP error 412 Unable to
refresh lock for http://myorigin.server.tld/info/refs LOCK HTTP error
412 Unable to refresh lock for http://myorigin.server.tld/info/refs
LOCK HTTP error 412 Unable to refresh lock for
http://myorigin.server.tld/info/refs LOCK HTTP error 412 Unable to
refresh lock for http://myorigin.server.tld/info/refs LOCK HTTP error
412 Unable to refresh lock for http://myorigin.server.tld/info/refs
LOCK HTTP error 412 Unable to refresh lock for
http://myorigin.server.tld/info/refs LOCK HTTP error 412 Unable to
refresh lock for http://myorigin.server.tld/info/refs LOCK HTTP error
412 Unable to refresh lock for http://myorigin.server.tld/info/refs
LOCK HTTP error 412 Unable to refresh lock for
http://myorigin.server.tld/info/refs LOCK HTTP error 412 Unable to
refresh lock for http://myorigin.server.tld/info/refs LOCK HTTP error
412 Unable to refresh lock for http://myorigin.server.tld/info/refs
LOCK HTTP error 412 Unable to refresh lock for
http://myorigin.server.tld/info/refs Updating remote server info
UNLOCK HTTP error 400 fatal: git-http-push failed To
http://myorigin.server.tld  ! [remote rejected] mybranch -> mybranch
error: failed to push some refs to 'http://myorigin.server.tld'
```

Comment: The [all zero ref is definitely a bad sign](//stackoverflow.com/a/18982443/2747593). Do you have any hooks active? Does the output of e.g. `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph` show anything interesting? What kind of server are you pushing to?

Comment: @ScottWeldon: the all-zero ref is because `mybranch` doesn't exist in the Git repository on the server. @DavidVanderElst: The failed lock refreshes are resulting in the failed push. It really looks as though this is a dumb protocol push op, which is generally a bad idea. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14488077/git-push-hangs-over-dumb-https-after-http-1-1-100-continue (and specify your Git version).